# Derivative of an inverse

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)=2x^3+7x−1$, and let $g(x)$ be the inverse of $f(x)$. Then find $g′(191/4)$. I know only one way of doing this. Solving the cubic equation for x and then differentiating it. This is too too long. How to solve it more easily?

Comment: Hint: $ \frac{d}{dx} f^{-1} = \frac{1}{f^{\prime}\left(f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)} $.

Comment: Will you please elaborate? How? Why?...

Comment: Take a look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231801/question-about-derivatives-of-inverses-functions?rq=1

Comment: consider user103828's initial comment while referring to the 2nd diagram at this webpage. http://mathuprising.comlu.com/inverse-functions.html <shameless self promotion>

Answer (score 5):

$g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$ means that $f \circ g(x)=f(g(x))=x=g(f(x))$

You take the derivative and get

$g'(x) \times f'(g(x))=1$ and also $f'(x) \times g'(f(x))=1$

Answer (score 4):

In order to not confuse the variables of the inverse function with the variables of the function itself, let :

$y=f(x)=2x^3+7x−1=X$

$Y=g(X)=x$

One little picture says more than a long speech! : See below

[image]

$\frac{dg}{dX}=\frac{1}{\frac{df}{dx}}$

For $X=\frac{191}{4}$ we have $y=\frac{191}{4}=2x^3+7x-1$ which real root is $x=\frac{5}{2}$

$\frac{1}{\frac{df}{dx}}=\frac{1}{6x^2+7}=\frac{1}{6\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+7}=\frac{2}{89}$

$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{1}{\frac{df}{dx}}=\frac{2}{89}$

where $X=y=\frac{191}{4}$  and $Y=x=\frac{5}{2}$

One see on the graph on right, which represents the inverse function, that the point considered is at abscissa $\frac{191}{4}$ as specified in the wording of the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: First solve for $x_0$ such that: $2x^3 + 7x - 1 = \frac{191}{4}$, then apply inverse function theorem for derivative: $g'(f(x_0)) = \dfrac{1}{f'(x_0)}$